# Problems while selecting data from the table?

Tags: mysql, sql, python-2.7, select, group-by

I have a table like the one given below.

```
View        :    Cat    :    Name
abcView      
abcView      abcCategory2
abcView      abcCategory2    abcFilter
abcView2      
abcView2     abcCategory
abcView2    
abcView3
```

View is the parent of Cat and Cat is the parent of Name. View can never be empty if Cat exists. Similarly, Cat can never be empty if Name exists. I want to fetch data in such a way that I dont want any empty spaces or replications in my result. If there are two entries, one with a child and one without a child then I only want to show the entry with the child. But if there is no child then I just want to return the parent(s) name.

```
View      :   Cat      :    Name
abcView    abcCateogry2  abcFilter
abcView2   abcCategory
abcView3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could select all entries, where a name exists by

```
SELECT View, Cat, Name
FROM yourTable
WHERE Name NOT NULL
```

then union it with all entries, where just a cat exists (and no name)

```
SELECT View, Cat, Name
FROM yourTable
WHERE Name IS NOT NULL
UNION
SELECT View, Cat, NULL
FROM yourTable
WHERE Cat IS NOT NULL AND
      Name IS NULL AND
      Cat NOT IN (SELECT Cat FROM yourTable WHERE Name IS NOT NULL)
```

and finally union it with all entries, where just a view (and no name and cat exists)

```
SELECT View, Cat, Name
FROM yourTable
WHERE Name IS NOT NULL
UNION
SELECT View, Cat, NULL
FROM yourTable
WHERE Cat IS NOT NULL AND
      Name IS NULL AND
      Cat NOT IN (SELECT Cat FROM yourTable WHERE Name IS NOT NULL)
UNION
SELECT View, NULL, NULL
FROM yourTable
WHERE View IS NOT NULL AND
      Cat IS NULL AND
      View NOT IN (SELECT View FROM yourTable WHERE Cat IS NOT NULL)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.View, MAX(a.Cat) Cat, MAX(a.Name) AS `name` 
FROM tableA a 
GROUP BY a.View
```

Comment: This is not working when I have more than one children for each parent. Each parent has multiple children.

Answer (score 0):

Try following query and check whether it is working or not. It is working in sample data but may create problem in data which you have in table. I am combining three column and checking same combination is not exist in table so you will get one row with max level possible:

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE
(
[View] VARCHAR(100),
Cat VARCHAR(100),
Name VARCHAR(100)
)

INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES 
('abcView','',''),      
('abcView','abcCategory1',''),
('abcView','abcCategory2',''),
('abcView','abcCategory2','abcFilter'),
('abcView2','',''),
('abcView2','abcCategory',''),
('abcView2','',''),
('abcView3','','')


    SELECT 
    t1.[View],
    t1.Cat,
    t1.Name 
FROM 
    @TABLE AS t1 
WHERE 
    (
        SELECT 
            COUNT(*) 
        FROM 
            @TABLE 
        WHERE 
            ([View]+'-'+Cat+'-'+Name) LIKE '%'+ REPLACE((t1.[View]+'-'+t1.Cat+'-'+t1.Name),'--','-') + '%'
    ) = 1
```